# PHP Unsupported characters str_replace not working

Tags: php, string

I am trying to replace the unsupported characters or characters in some other font in PHP. I am new to PHP. Trying to do this:

```
$news_val = str_replace('','',str_replace('”','"',str_replace('’','\'',str_replace('“','"',$news_val))));
```

But not working. I need any one help.

Answer (score 0):

seem to be you want to replace multiple characters.

hopefully this tutorial may help you to avoid nasted code and array multiple character example.

```
$string = "The quick brown fox jumped over the lazy dog";
$search = array('quick', 'fox', 'jumped over', 'dog');
$replace = array('hungry', 'wolf', 'ate', 'mouse');
echo str_replace($search, $replace, $string);
```

reference :

http://www.electrictoolbox.com/php-str-replace-associative-array/

Special character List :
http://www.degraeve.com/reference/specialcharacters.php

You can also use htmlentities :
http://php.net/manual/en/function.htmlentities.php

Comment: Actually the double quotation which i want to replace is in some other font format. I can't paste exactly here. Because its also not supporting in the editor here. Its automatically converting to right/left double quote...

Answer (score 0):

use the function `htmlentities()` to escape from unsupported characters